# Convert double to int error - Draw line numbers on RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I have some code from an old VB.NET project that draws line numbers in a PictureBox control. I used an online converter to quickly convert the code over to C#. However; I am getting two errors.

1. "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'" which I'm
   guessing is referring to the second set of parameters.
2. Use of unassigned local variable 'y'.

I've tried tinkering around with the brackets in case it was to do with the difference of the syntax but that didn't solve the issue.

This is the code that I am using (I previously got this from Google for VB.NET)

```
  private void DrawRichTextBoxLineNumbers(ref Graphics g)
        {
            {
                var withBlock = TextEditBox;
                float font_height;
                font_height = withBlock.GetPositionFromCharIndex(withBlock.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(2)).Y
             - withBlock.GetPositionFromCharIndex(withBlock.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1)).Y;
                if (font_height == 0)
                    return;


                // Get the first line index and location
                int first_index;
                int first_line;
                int first_line_y;
                first_index = withBlock.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + (font_height / (double)3)));
                first_line = withBlock.GetLineFromCharIndex(first_index);
                first_line_y = withBlock.GetPositionFromCharIndex(first_index).Y;

                // Print on the PictureBox the visible line numbers of the RichTextBox
                g.Clear(Control.DefaultBackColor);
                int i = first_line;
                float y;
                while (y < g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + g.VisibleClipBounds.Height)
                {
                    y = first_line_y + 2 + font_height * (i - first_line - 1);
                    g.DrawString((i).ToString(), withBlock.Font, Brushes.Gray, LineNumber.Width
              - g.MeasureString((i).ToString(), withBlock.Font).Width, y);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

The error is coming from this line:

```
        first_index = withBlock.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + (font_height / (double)3)));
```

What changes can I make to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've tried removing the 'double' in the brackets as well and re-arranging stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here is problematic:

```
new Point(0, g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + (font_height / (double)3)
```

The `new Point(int, int)` constructor is the only one that takes two numbers, and hence requires a pair of `int`s. `g.VisibleClipBounds.Y` [is a float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.visibleclipbounds?view=netframework-4.7.2) (part of a RectangleF), font_height is also a float, and that 3 is cast to a double. None of it's an int. a `float+float/double` results in a double. VB would probably convert that implicitly/automagically depending on the settings, cos VB programmers like to play fast and loose with things like datatypes ;) but C# demands more precise coding and won't automatically take a variable type that can hold a large number and shove it into a a type that only holds a small number (a.k.a a narrowing conversion)

You can convert to to an int (but I don't guarantee that it produces the intended effect) by casting it after the math is done:

```
new Point(0, (int)(g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + (font_height / (double)3))
```

---

The other error, `y`  is not assigned a value before it is used; C# can foresee some code paths that lead to use before assignment. Give it a sensible default value (what that looks like, I've no idea.. `-1` perhaps?):

```
float y; //make it -1 maybe?
while (y < g.VisibleClipBounds.Y + g.VisibleClipBounds.Height)
```

Comment: Ok that solved the issue but there is another line of code for the paint event of the PictureBox that has the code "     DrawRichTextBoxLineNumbers(e.Graphics);" but it errors out saying "Argument 1 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword"

Comment: So, pass it with the ref keyword? Please note that asking Question A, getting an answer, then dragging it onto Question B, then moving th goalposts again and turning it into Question C, until someone has fixed every compiler error, is not what we do

Comment: I did that just before you commented back and it errors out with "A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"

Comment: So, make it not a property or indexer.. `var x = e.Graphics; MethodBlahBlah(ref x);`..

Comment: It should be ref x, not ref g as that's not the variable name

Comment: It doesn't seem to even need to be `ref` in the method signature - the method body doesn't reassign ref to be anything else. I'd remove all mentions of `ref`; it's very very rare that anyone would need to use it. I note often that VB.NET people seem prone to slapping ByRef in all sorts of places it's not needed; possibly a holdrover from the VB6 days

Comment: Ok I will make those changes now, thanks for the advice. A bit of a novice when it comes to C#, as you can probably tell.